# Fatal error , can't unwrap optional none

Tags: swift

This is really a simple problem , but I just can't solve it , I have the following full code

```
  var numberoftimer:Int = 0



func increment(){

        numberoftimer = numberoftimer + 1 //error is here,breakpoint,no error message

    if numberoftimer>4{
        falafel1.center = CGPointMake(200, 100)



    }


}



@IBOutlet var fryer:UIImageView
@IBOutlet var order : UILabel
var NumberOfFlafel:UInt32!

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Custom initialization
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NumberOfFlafel = arc4random()%11
    if NumberOfFlafel<2{
        order.text = "make \(NumberOfFlafel) falafel"
    }
    order.text = "make \(NumberOfFlafel) falafels"








}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let t = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

    if t.view == falafel1{
        let p = t.locationInView(self.view)

        falafel1.center = p




        if CGRectIntersectsRect(falafel1.frame, fryer.frame){
            falafel1.center = CGPointMake(385, 192)
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1 , target: self, selector: "increment", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }

        }
```

This gives me a run time error saying can't unwrap optional none , this is because I'm accessing something that doesn't have a value , but in this case , how can I solve this problem

Comment: As explained in the answer to the "duplicate", you have to put whitespace  around both sides or around neither side of the `+`. In your case it is treated as a prefix unary operator.

Comment: I did put a white space around it , it doesn't solve my problem , and I wish that the question gets opened

Comment: ... which I have just done immediately after noticing  your edit. - Apart from that, it would be helpful if you copy your actual code, including the proper upper/lower-case. For example, it is `Int`, not `int`, and `func`, not `Func`.

Comment: ...and including proper indenting

Comment: Correction : runtime error not compile time error

Answer (score 0):

```
var num: Int?
```

declares an *optional* variable, which is automatically initialized as `nil` (aka *optional None*), indicating
a "missing" value. Therefore

```
num = num! + 1
```

crashes at runtime, because no value has been assigned to the variable.

Using an optional seems not to be necessary in your case, so you should declare it as

```
var num: Int = 0 // integer variable with initial value zero
```

and remove the "unwrapping" operator `!` in your method:

```
func function() {
    num = num + 1 // Or simply: ++num
    if num > 5 {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried your solutuion , but it didn't work and crashed in the part when the UIImageView (hence named falafel)intersects the the fryer , it crashes and opens the debugger, this could be a bug or something wrong in my code logic

Comment: @AbdullahOssamaOmari: Just to make sure: You did not set a breakpoint?